# Installing PODS with CocoaPods - First time install

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am totally new to CocoaPods and I am using [this](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/cocoapods-dependancy-management-for-xcode/139) tutorial to integrate [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/bpodial) project into my ios project. This is what my Podfile in my xcode looks like

```
pod 'BPODial', '~> 0.0.1'
```

Now when I attempt to install it I get the following

```
Admin:Test Proj$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] The platform of the target `Pods` (iOS 8.2) is not compatible with `BPODial (0.0.1)` which has a minimum requirement of OS X 10.8.
```

I am using xcode version 6.2 and I am not sure what this error means ? Is there  a way for me to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the pod you are trying to use is for OSX, not iOS.  So it will not work in a mobile application.

Just in case your interested, here is a tutorial for how to make a knob in iOS.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/56885/custom-control-for-ios-tutorial-a-reusable-knob